# All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am implementing a pipeline using important features selection and then using the same features to train my random forest classifier. Following is my code.

```py
m = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 10)
m.fit(train_cv_x,train_cv_y)
sel = SelectFromModel(m, prefit=True)
X_new = sel.transform(train_cv_x)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(5000)

model = Pipeline([('m', m),('sel', sel),('X_new', X_new),('clf', clf),])
params = {'clf__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']}

gs = GridSearchCV(model, params)
gs.fit(train_cv_x,train_cv_y)
```

So `X_new` are the new features selected via `SelectFromModel` and `sel.transform`. Then I want to train my RF using the new features selected.

I am getting the following error:

```
All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform, 
ExtraTreesClassifier ...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like the traceback says: each step in your pipeline needs to have a `fit()` and `transform()` method (except the last, which just needs `fit()`.  This is because a pipeline chains together transformations of your data at each step.

`sel.transform(train_cv_x)` is not an estimator and doesn't meet this criterion.

In fact, it looks like based on what you're trying to do, you can leave this step out.  Internally, `('sel', sel)` already does this transformation--that's why it's included in the pipeline.

Secondly, `ExtraTreesClassifier` (the first step in your pipeline), doesn't have a `transform()` method, either.  You can verify that [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html), in the class docstring.  Supervised learning models aren't made for transforming data; they're made for fitting on it and predicting based off that.

What type of classes are able to do transformations?

- Ones that *scale* your data.  See [preprocessing and normalization](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing).
- Ones that *transform* your data (in some other way than the above).  [Decomposition](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.decomposition) and other unsupervised learning methods do this.

Without reading between the lines too much about what you're trying to do here, this would work for you:

1. First split x and y using `train_test_split`.  The test dataset produced by this is held out for final testing, and the train dataset within `GridSearchCV`'s cross-validation will be further broken out into smaller train and validation sets.
2. Build a pipeline that satisfies what your traceback is trying to tell you.
3. Pass that pipeline to `GridSearchCV`, `.fit()` that grid search on X_train/y_train, then `.score()` it on X_test/y_test.

Roughly, that would look like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=444)

sel = SelectFromModel(ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=444), 
                      threshold='mean')
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5000, random_state=444)

model = Pipeline([('sel', sel), ('clf', clf)])
params = {'clf__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']}

gs = GridSearchCV(model, params)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

# How well do your hyperparameter optimizations generalize
# to unseen test data?
gs.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Two examples for further reading:

- [Pipelining: chaining a PCA and a logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_digits_pipe.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-digits-pipe-py)
- [Sample pipeline for text feature extraction and evaluation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sample-pipeline-for-text-feature-extraction-and-evaluation)

Answer (score 3):

You may also get the error in the title if you were oversampling or undersampling your data using `imblearn` module and fitting it into a model in a pipeline. If you got this message, then it means you have imported [`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). Import [`imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline`](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) instead and you're golden. For example,

```py
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('o', SMOTE()), ('svc', SVC())])
```

The problem is, if you're sampling your data, the intermediate steps obviously need to sample the data as well, which is not supported by sklearn's `Pipeline` but is supported by imblearn's `Pipeline`.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. After a long time, I found this.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened because the first transformer you pass in a pipeline must have both a fit and transform method.

```
m = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 10)
m.fit(train_cv_x,train_cv_y)
```

Here m does not have a transform method as ExtraTreesClassifier model does not have a transform method and so fails in the pipeline.

So change the order of the pipeline and add another transformer for the first step in the pipeline